# Data returns array instead of an object

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

Its probably some stupid mistake but tell me what am i doing wrong?

I made it in 2 ways.

- In the first solution i send the data from my VsCode to the database and then retrieve it.
- In the second solution i just send parsed json file as a resposne directly from VsCode folder.

I want the **data** from the **first solution** return me an object (like in the 2nd solution)  not an array.

**1 solution:**

[image: array]

```
//IMPORTING TO DATABASE

const questions = JSON.parse(
  fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/questions.json`, "utf-8")
);

const importData = async () => {
  try {
    await Questions.create(questions);
    console.log("Data successfully loaded!");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  process.exit();
};


//MODEL

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const questionsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  beginner: [
    {
      questionText: String,
      answerOptions: Array,
    },
  ],
  intermediate: [
    {
      questionText: String,
      answerOptions: Array,
    },
  ],
  advanced: [
    {
      questionText: String,
      answerOptions: Array,
    },
  ],
});

// RESPONSE
const getAllQuestions = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const data = await Questions.find();

    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      status: "fail",
      message: err,
    });
  }

  next();
};
```

my json structure:

```
{
  "beginner": [...],
  "intermediate": [...],
   "advanced": [...],
}
```

**2nd solution:**

When i just simply read the json file and send it as a response it works correctly:

[image: object]

```
const fs = require("fs");
const dataPath = require("path").resolve(__dirname, "../data/questions.json");

const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(dataPath));

exports.getAllQuestions = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      status: "fail",
      message: err,
    });
  }

  next();
};
```

Comment: Well, `Questions.find();` returns all question documents in your db. Are you trying to return one specific question document? If yes, use `Question.findOne()` or `Question.findById(id)`.

Comment: I have it as a one document that has questions seperated  in difficulties, so there is only one document.

Comment: Ok, ```Question.findOne()``` worked. Its kinda weird since i have only one document and 
 ```Question.find()``` should differentiate that

Comment: Disagree :) I'd rather have `.find()` always behave the same (returning an array instead of returning a single document when only one document is present). 

But apart from that I think your db-design is not optimal - shouldn't each question be a single document? You could then add a property like `difficulty` to differentiate between beginner/intermediate/advanced.

Comment: Yeah, will make a refactor of that json file. Single document looks strange. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To add further to @eol's response, if you want to query on the entry db collection, you need to pass an empty object to the `Question.find({})` method.

If you want to return one of the different difficulties within the doc, then I believe you treat the response like any other object with properties.